# I can't access wp-admin. I'm using NGINX Ubuntu

Tags: wordpress, nginx

My website can be accessed, it's just that the Wp-admin section can't be opened like this
[This site can’t be reached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOb3D.png)

This is my code

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root /home/nicho/projects/strongbee-web-3.0;
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name _;

    location ~* \.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|ico|wmv|3gp|avi|mpg|mpeg|mp4|flv|mp3|mid|js|css|wml|swf|ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|woff2)$ {
        expires max;
        add_header Pragma public;
        add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
    }

    location / {
        #file ($uri) or directory ($uri/)? if not, redirect to /index.php + query string
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        index  index.html index.htm index.php;
    }

    location /wp-admin {
        index index.php;
    }

    rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Remove that `location /wp-admin { ... }`.

Comment: That's no work for me. Is any other way?

Comment: Try removing both WP-admin blocks. The first one is not necessary since the index will try index.html, index.html, and index.php on all locations inside / anyhow, including wp-admin. The second "rewrite wp-admin" rule is not necessary unless you have renamed the wp-admin folder or have otherwise done something nonstandard with it. Your configuration otherwise looks good, let us know if you have any further issues.